# R equivalent for grep -wf

Tags: r

What is the best way to select a subset from `fileA` based on patterns in `fileB`? 
Ex below: I want to match `fileB` with the column `IsomIR` in `fileA` (no matches in this example).

fileA

```
                                IsomIR        100         106         122        124       126         134        141
1 hsa-let-7a-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCT  0.5523442  0.03172328  0.36802914  0.4566302 1.4500921  1.29752724 -0.3449874
2  hsa-let-7a-5p_AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGT -0.1878607 -0.18780651 -0.05246163 -0.4256350 0.7401029  0.21164568 -0.9593107
3 hsa-let-7a-5p_AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT  0.2786761  1.26500857  0.25548324  1.1209635 0.3973024  1.20270323 -0.9247950
4  hsa-let-7a-5p_CGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGT -0.3736628 -0.56529189 -0.07579734 -0.2856444 0.4427098  0.16931756 -0.9746290
5 hsa-let-7a-5p_CGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT  0.2109184  1.30968772  0.17753460  1.0215007 0.5122301  1.24588266 -0.9321214
6   hsa-let-7a-5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAG -0.6084397 -0.38716052  0.22242122 -0.3468830 0.8116086 -0.06074317 -1.2598679
```

fileB

```
[1] hsa-miR-21-5p_GTAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC   hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGACC  
[3] hsa-miR-135b-5p_TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTGAA hsa-miR-135b-5p_TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTG  
[5] hsa-miR-135b-5p_TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTGA  hsa-miR-195-5p_TAGCAGCACAGAAATATTGGAAA
```

I tried this:

```
> match(fileB,fileA)
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Clarify your question by showing the sample result you want.  Also, on what do you want to match?

Comment: question updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fileA[fileA$IsomIR %in% fileB,]
```

This matches the content of column `IsomIR` with the content of `fileB` and selects only the rows in `fileA` where there's a match.